# OSX Drag and drop sensitivity setting?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, drag-and-drop

Is there a setting in OSX Lion that allows me to change the drag and drop threshold? I am using a Wacom intuos4 tablet and when working fast I sometimes drag files or tabs instead of just clicking them. Resulting in some frustration when a browser tab detaches itself into a new window or a folder is moved into a sibling folder.

I have been vigorously searching the internet and all I could find was information on this feature in windows and gnome :P

Just to be clear: I want to heighten the amount of pixels a mouse pointer is allowed to move while pressed without triggering the drag behavior.

Anyone?

Comment: Tough one, usually apple doesn't allow any customization of these settings.

Comment: I am starting to think it's just not possible.. Was hoping for some sort of 'defaults' option

Answer (score 4):

Show current drag and drop delay (from Terminal):

```
defaults read -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay
```

Set a global 0.4 second delay for drag and drop:

```
defaults write -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int 400
```

Set an app-specific delay of 3 seconds for iPhoto:

```
defaults write com.apple.iPhoto NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int 3000
```

See also http://rixstep.com/2/20060901,00.shtml

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options that you can try:

### Mac preferences

From the Apple support page ["Mac 101: Set your preferences"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2490), there's a chapter that explains how to [Customize your mouse, and trackpad](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2490#l1):

> We all type, point, and click differently. That's why it's important to make sure that you optimize your keyboard, mouse, or trackpad.

---

### Third-party application

I've played around with [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) in the past, it's currently the version 4.8 released April 2, 2012.

> TinkerTool is an application that gives you access to additional preference settings Apple has built into Mac OS X. This allows to activate hidden features in the operating system and in some of the applications delivered with the system.

The minimum system requirements are: *Mac OS X 10.6 or later*

**Note:**
Haven't seen this new version and what news they bring, but give it a go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Glad to have at least some activity here ;) But I cannot find the answer for my question in the Mac 101 page, nor is it a specific setting in tinkertool.. or am i missing something?